# My aggregate doesn't save the state on postgresql

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I'm trying to coding an aggregate function to do the bit_and beetween the columns of a table stored as bytea.
The function used to do it substring the bytea using a the length of a binary string 
% 8 ( the byte length) and returns the bit and beetween all the section of the bytea that satysfy:

section & binary_string = binary_string

I defined the aggregate "testaggregate" to aggregate all the values from query like

```
select testaggregate (bytea_field, binary_string_in_varchar) 
from tab1
```

here is the aggregate code

```
create aggregate testaggregate (bytea, character varying) (
 sfunc =aggand($0, $1, $2),
 stype = bit varying<p> 
);
```

where aggand is :

```
declare  
  ret bit varying; 
  begin 
    if suband($2,$3) is not null then 
      if $1 is null  then ret = suband($2,$3);
         else    
       ret =$1 & suband($2,$3); 
     end if;
     else
     ret =null;    
    end if;   
  return ret ;  
end;
```

and "suband" is the function that calculate the bit_and for each row.

My first problem is when i execute the aggregate function it doesn't return a single row but as many rows as the table has.
The second question and the most important is why the aggregate internal state is always null after the execution of aggand.

Sorry for my english and the bad indentation of the code this is my first question. Thanks to all

Answer (score 1):

It looks like calling a state function instead aggregate, with some wrong aggregate definition

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION s_func(int, int, int)
RETURNS int AS $$
BEGIN
  RETURN $1 + COALESCE($2,0) + COALESCE($3,0);
END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE AGGREGATE sgg(int, int) (sfunc = s_func, stype = int, INITCOND = 0);

postgres=# SELECT sgg(i, i+1) FROM generate_series(1,3) g(i);
 sgg 
-----
  15
(1 row)
```